# preg_match for number error?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a form, where the user must fill in his id card number. Id number of cards has a length of 16 character. I want to check whether the string entered is correct only a number with a length of 16 characters?

i have this code:

```
<?php
$nik=1234567891234567;

if(!preg_match('/^[1-9][0-9]{16}$/', $nik)){
    echo 'nooooo';
    exit;
}else{
    echo 'yesss';
    exit;
}
?>
```

the result will echoed nooooo, is there anything wrong with its regex?

Comment: `/^[0-9]+$/` is the one.

Comment: @tilz0R that's wrong. What about `10`? It's an integer, but your regex would reject it.

Comment: @EdCottrell, so how can i check it using preg_match? i have updated my question

Comment: @Gumilar Well, for starters, don't try to treat a number as a string. Your user's submitted data will be a string; don't test by pretending it's a number. Use an actual string. Then see if you even have this problem.

Comment: Your pattern hints that your id card numbers cannot start with a zero.  Is that true? because you don't say so in your plan English explanation of your task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The Regex Problem

What you want is something like this:

```
<?php
$nik=1234567891234567;

var_dump($nik);

if(preg_match('/^[1-9]\d{15}$/', $nik)){
    echo "Contains only numbers";
    exit;
}else{
    echo "Contains non-numeric characters";
    exit;
}
```

[Here's a demo](https://3v4l.org/TXvC9).

This will match a string with exactly 16 characters; the first can be `1-9`, but the rest can be any digit. Your regex, `/^[1-9][0-9]{16}$/`, matches a character in the range `1-9`, then 16 characters in the range `0-9`, for a total of 17 characters.

## Integer Size

Also, your code has a logical flaw: your number is larger than the maximum integer value on a 32-bit system, as stated in [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.overflow). The largest value on any system can be determined by checking the constant `PHP_INT_MAX`. For a 32-bit system, this is `2147483647`. That has fewer than 16 characters, so your code will not work reliably on a 32-bit system.

## Strings Versus Integers

Also, your post said you're getting this info from a user via a form. In that case, you will be receiving a string, not an integer. For example, if your field is named `nik`, then you would access the info with `$_POST['nik']` (for a POST form) or `$_GET['nik']` (for a GET form). Then, just use it as a string; it's not really a number, anyway.

## Other Considerations

You're checking for a 16-character number. This sounds like something involving credit cards. *If* you are doing credit card processing, you should know that there are major security implications and compliance issues related to processing cards on your server. I can't give you legal advice, and how to properly process a credit card is much too broad a topic for this site. But I will say this: if this is credit card data, you *do not* want to do it this way unless you have a very large budget for compliance issues, auditing, and the like. You should look into using PayPal, Stripe, or a similar vendor to handle this.

Comment: thank you verry much for your explanations. i'm checking 16 characters number is for identity card, in my country its length is 16 chars.
yes, i access the info with $_POST['nik'] and it gave me string value, and thanks a lot your answer really solved my problem, but, can i really check that the string value is only contain numbers and not alphabet or any special chars? and what's the different between 1234567890 as string and 1234567890 as number?